# Avoid duplicate mapping in MapStruct

Tags: java, objectmapper, mapstruct

I have two MapStruct mapper classes where some of the target/source classes and some of the fields are exactly the same:

```
  ///Mapper 1
  @Mappings({
          @Mapping(target = "tenantTitleId", expression = "java(order.getProductID())"),
          @Mapping(target = "tenantId", constant = "MGM"),
          @Mapping(target = "titleName", expression = "java(order.getProductDesc())"),
          @Mapping(target = "orders", source = "order", qualifiedBy = ComplexMapper.class),
  })
  @BeanMapping(ignoreByDefault = true)
  public abstract TargetClass toTargetClass(SourceClass sourceClass) throws Exception;

  ///Mapper 2
  @Mappings({
          @Mapping(target = "tenantTitleId", expression = "java(order.getProductID())"),
          @Mapping(target = "tenantId", constant = "MGM"),
          @Mapping(target = "titleName", expression = "java(order.getProductDesc())"),
          @Mapping(target = "orders", source = "order", qualifiedBy = AnotherComplexMapper.class),
  })
  @BeanMapping(ignoreByDefault = true)
  public abstract TargetClass toTargetClass(SourceClass sourceClass) throws Exception;
```

The first 3 mappings are exactly the same. Is there a way to not repeat this mapping the MapStruct way?

Comment: If all of these mappings have the same `TargetClass` and different `SourceClass` I think that there is no way to achieve that. You can experiment with some abstract class of `SourceClass` and maps all similar fields in one mapping method, but I didn't test yet if mapsturct allows you to have abstract class in argument method or it needs only concrete class. You can try and let know if it helps :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Mapping Composition](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#mapping-composition) in order to avoid the duplication.

e.g.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
@Mapping(target = "tenantTitleId", expression = "productID")
@Mapping(target = "tenantId", constant = "MGM")
@Mapping(target = "titleName", expression = "productDesc")
public @interface CommonMappings { }
```

And then your mapper will look like:

```
  ///Mapper 1
  @CommonMappings
  @Mapping(target = "orders", source = "order", qualifiedBy = ComplexMapper.class)
  @BeanMapping(ignoreByDefault = true)
  public abstract TargetClass toTargetClass(SourceClass sourceClass) throws Exception;

  ///Mapper 2
  @CommonMappings
  @Mapping(target = "orders", source = "order", qualifiedBy = AnotherComplexMapper.class)
  @BeanMapping(ignoreByDefault = true)
  public abstract TargetClass toTargetClass(SourceClass sourceClass) throws Exception;
```